# tensorflow run takes forever on small data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying a simple example of a book where I have a train data sample with 892 lines, the usual titanic survival textbook example. I define:

```
def read_csv(batch_size, file_path, record_defaults):

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([file_path])
    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # decode_csv will convert a Tensor from type string (the text line) in
    # a tuple of tensor columns with the specified defaults, which also
    # sets the data type for each column
    decoded = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)


    # batch actually reads the file and loads "batch_size" rows in a single tensor
    return tf.train.shuffle_batch(decoded,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  capacity=batch_size * 50,
                                  min_after_dequeue=batch_size)
def inputs():
    passenger_id, survived, pclass, name, sex, age, sibsp, parch, ticket, fare, cabin, embarked = \
        read_csv(BATCH_SIZE, file_path, record_defaults)

    # convert categorical data
    is_first_class = tf.to_float(tf.equal(pclass, [1]))
    is_second_class = tf.to_float(tf.equal(pclass, [2]))
    is_third_class = tf.to_float(tf.equal(pclass, [3]))

    gender = tf.to_float(tf.equal(sex, ["female"]))

    # Finally we pack all the features in a single matrix;
    # We then transpose to have a matrix with one example per row and one feature per column.
    features = tf.transpose(tf.pack([is_first_class, is_second_class, is_third_class, gender, age]))


    print 'shape of features', features.get_shape()
    return features, survived
```

And now I try to do:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 1]), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(0., name="bias")
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print 'tf was run'
    X,Y = inputs()
    print 'inputs!'
    sess.run(Y)
```

and I see

```
'tf was run!'
'inputs!'
```

but the `run` part hangs forever (or at least a very long tiem). I'm running this on Jupyter with a 2.7 kernel and `tf` version `0.12`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the line

```
return tf.train.shuffle_batch(decoded,
                              batch_size=batch_size,
                              capacity=batch_size * 50,
                              min_after_dequeue=batch_size)
```

You're **defining** the operation of extraction of values from the queue and the creation of batches.

If you look at the complete signature of the method you'll notice that there's a parameter that refers to a number of threads.

```
tf.train.shuffle_batch(
tensors,
batch_size,
capacity,
min_after_dequeue,
num_threads=1,
seed=None, enqueue_many=False, shapes=None,
allow_smaller_final_batch=False, shared_name=None, name=None)
```

I'm pointing this out because the operations you defined are executed from some threads.
The thread **must** be started and stopped, this function does not do this for you. The only thing that this function does, about the thread handling, is to add `num_thread` to a queue.

In practice, to start and stop the threads you need to define within the session an operation that wake up the threads in the queue:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:

    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 1]), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(0., name="bias")
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print 'tf was run'
    X,Y = inputs()
    # define a coordinator to start and stop the threads
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    # wake up the threads
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    print 'inputs!'
    sess.run(Y) #execute operation
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    coord.request_stop()
    # Wait for threads to finish.
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Or use `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` which takes care of all the initialization and starting of queue runners.